# Displaying the same webpage in a popup window using WebView2?

Tags: visual-c++, popupwindow, webview2

MFC, Win32, VC++

Code:

```
if (m_pImpl->m_webView)
{
    m_pImpl->m_webView->ExecuteScript(L"window.open(url)",
        Callback<ICoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler>(
            [](HRESULT error, PCWSTR result) -> HRESULT { return S_OK; })
        .Get());
}
```

If I use `window.print()` the JavaScript executes and I see a print dialog. So I know it is working. But nothing happens when I use `window.open(url)`. Why? I have not disabled popups.

Even the official [Sample App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/samples/webview2apissample) won't display the page in a popup window when using its **Execute Script** feature.

---

I should clarify `m_webView`:

```
wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2> m_webView;
```

---

#### Update

Part of the issue is that using `url` is wrong. If I use `'https://www.microsoft.com'` it works.

But I am trying to open a local html file on my local driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Step 1

```
CString CWebBrowser::GetLocationURL()
{
    CString url;
    if (m_pImpl->m_webView)
    {
        wil::unique_cotaskmem_string uri;
        m_pImpl->m_webView->get_Source(&uri);

        if (wcscmp(uri.get(), L"about:blank") == 0)
        {
            uri = wil::make_cotaskmem_string(L"");
        }

        url = uri.get();
    }

    return url;
}
```

#### Step 2

```
void CWebBrowser::ShowPrintUIFullScreen(const CString strUrl)
{
    if (m_pImpl->m_webView)
    {
        m_pImpl->m_webView->ExecuteScript(L"window.open('" + GetLocationURL() + L"')",
            Callback<ICoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler>(
                [](HRESULT error, PCWSTR result) -> HRESULT { return S_OK; })
            .Get());
    }
}
```

Works like a charm!